# Java: Can I convert List of Object to List of String[] and vice versa?

Tags: java, list, object, casting

Is this possible without going through the list and casting the objects?

I also need to convert `List<Object>` to `List<T>` (T = predefined Object) if it's possible?

Edit: for clarification, I'm trying to use `List<Object>` as a return type of a class method that is widely used in my code.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "converting": the less destructive thing to do is to cast to an untyped List. From that you can cast to a typed List<?>, but it won't cast the objects inside it. It would be nice to know why you would do such a thing (losing type safety is generally not a good idea).

Comment: @Viruzzo, I understand that this is not the best way to do it but I'm trying to use code that's already available, and sometimes I use it to get `List<String[]>` and other times it's for `List<T>` (T = predefined Object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This is simply not a valid conversion, because not all `Object`s are `String[]`.

---

<sub>You could have determined this for yourself in 2 lines of code.</sub>

---

#### Edit

It sounds like you need to write the method more generically. Something like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getGenericList()
{
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

This can return a `List<String[]>` like so:

```
List<String[]> listOfStringArr = getGenericList();
```

Comment: Yes, it's giving me an error, which is why I asked the question. Maybe there's a way to do it that I didn't know about.

Comment: Declare it as a `List<String[]>`.

Comment: But it's not always `List<String[]>`, sometimes it's `List<T>`

Answer (score 9):

Actually, this is possible, because of type erasure. You can convert a parameterized type to a raw type, and vice-versa.

```
    List<Object> listO = new ArrayList<Object>( );
    listO.add( "Foo" );
    listO.add( "Bar" );

    List listQ = listO;
    List<String> listS = (List<String>) listQ;
```

However, this does *not* mean this is a good idea. This works around compile-time type-checking of parameterized types. If your List contains objects other than the type you expect, unexpected results may occur.

Answer (score 0):

No. What if the `Object` in the first list *isn't* actually `T`?

That being said, you can try to cast `List<Object>` to `List<T>` (be prepared for exceptions).

/e1
I don't know the specifics of your code, but it sounds like creating a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) would be beneficial to you.

Comment: I thought I could use `instanceof`?

Comment: @dee `foo instanceof T` where `foo` is an `Object` is not possible due to [type erasure](http://bit.ly/tGyKP4).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by definition. All classes in java extend Object. List of Objects can theoretically contain elements of every type your want. How do you want to convert something to specific type `T`?