# Casting arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I would like to cast an arrayList of objects into an arrayList of a specific object class. Cant you do it like when you cast a normal Object ?

```
JsonParser jParse = CallApi.getUsers(session);
//This object contains users
ArrayList<Object> unknownObject = jParse.getList();
ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList<User>)unknownObject;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Can I convert List of Object to List of String\[\] and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229936/java-can-i-convert-list-of-object-to-list-of-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: You can't. An `ArrayList<Object>` is not an `ArrayList<User>` even if the first one contains all `User` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helper method I just created for a similar task.

```
public static <newType, oldType> ArrayList<newType> castArrayList(ArrayList<oldType> list){
    ArrayList<newType> newlyCastedArrayList = new ArrayList<newType>();
    for(oldType listObject : list){
        newlyCastedArrayList.add((newType)listObject);
    }
    return newlyCastedArrayList;
}
```

it can be used like this

> ```
>         ArrayList<DesiredObjectType> myArrayList = Util.castArrayList(
>                arrayListOfAnotherType            
>           );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This code will always compile. **All generics (i.e. `<...>`) are removed during compilation anyway.**

```
List<User> users = (List)list;
```

But it's **not without risk**. If you are sure that your list only contains `User` objects, then you are safe. However, if there are other objects in the list, then it will probably lead to `ClassCastExceptions` in other places in your code. (e.g. if you iterate the list with a `for(User user : list)` loop.

Your IDE may show warnings if you add a cast like this. **You can hide these warnings, using annotations** (e.g. putting `@SurpressWarnings("unchecked")` above your method, or the line just above it).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<User> users = (List)list;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like this.

```
public static <T> List<T> cast(List list) {
    return list;
}
```

Then use it like this.

```
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<User> users = cast(list);
```